# particular solution of $(D^2+4)y=4x^2\cos 2x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a particular solution to the equation $$(D^2+4)y=4x^2\cos 2x$$

\begin{align}
y_p&=\frac{1}{D^2+4}(4x^2\cos 2x)\\
&=\frac{1}{D^2+4}\left[2x^2(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix})\right]\\
&=2\left[e^{2ix}\frac{1}{(D+2i)^2+4}x^2+e^{-2ix}\frac{1}{(D-2i)^2+4}x^2\right]\\
&=2\left[e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D(D+4i)}x^2+e^{-2ix}\frac{1}{D(D-4i)}x^2\right]\\
\end{align}
But I stuck at this point because how to solve $\frac{1}{D(D+4i)}x^2?$ The solution provided this

> \begin{align}
> &=2\left[e^{2ix}\frac{1}{D(D+4i)}x^2+e^{-2ix}\frac{1}{D(D-4i)}x^2\right]\\&=\frac{1}{4i}\left[e^{2ix}D^{-1}\left(2x^2+ix-\frac{1}{4}\right)-e^{-2ix}D^{-1}\left(2x^2-ix-\frac{1}{4}\right)\right]\\
> &=\frac{1}{24}[6x^2\cos 2x+x(8x^2-3)\sin 2x]
> \end{align}

I still can't figure out how they do this. Any help will be appreciated.

---

**Update**:
 Using @Isham answer I tired 
\begin{align}
&=\frac{1}{4i}\left[e^{2ix}D^{-1}\left(2x^2+ix-\frac{1}{4}\right)-e^{-2ix}D^{-1}\left(2x^2-ix-\frac{1}{4}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{4i}\left[e^{2ix}\left(2\frac{x^3}{3}+i\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{4}\right)-e^{-2ix}\left(2\frac{x^3}{3}-i\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{4}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{4i}\left[\frac{2x^3}{3}(e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix})+\frac{x^2i}{2}(e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix})-\frac{x}{4}(e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix})\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{4i}\left[\frac{2x^3}{3}2\cos 2x+\frac{x^2i}{2}2\cos 2x-\frac{x}{4}2\cos 2x\right]
\end{align}
But I think I am again Lost.

Comment: you have a sign error $x^2i/2$ shuld be positive not negative...and dont forget that $\sin x=\frac 1 {2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ for the factor $2x^3/3$ it should be a sine function not a cosine

Comment: I check my work but didn't find any sign error @Isham

Comment: that line before your final one has a sign error it should be positive not negative between the two exponetials

Comment: najm I edited your answer to show you where you made mistakes read correct and edit your answer once you corrected the mistakes

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: I realize my mistake. @Isham thanks a lot(+1)

Comment: Najmunahar yw... you can delete the lines I added in your answer. I just did it because it is more simple...

Comment: najm you are really close just don't mix sine and cosine functions.

Comment: @Isham I got the right answer :) tired now

Comment: Thats really great Najm good job!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E=\frac 1 {D+4i}=\frac 1 {4i}\frac 1 {(1+D/4i)}$$
$$E=\frac 1 {4i}({1+D/4i})^{-1}$$
Now you can use this ( after a certain number the derivative is zero for $x^2$:
$$\frac 1 {1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$
So we have that:
$$E=\frac 1 {4i}(1-\frac D {4i}-\frac {D^2}{16}+........)$$
Apply the operator on $x^2$

Comment: $(1-\frac{D}{4i}-\frac{D^2}{16}+\cdots)x^2=x^2-\frac{1}{4i}2x-\frac{1}{16}2+0+0+\cdots=x^2-\frac{x}{2i}-\frac{1}{8}$ but the solution expect $x^2+\frac{ix}{2}-\frac{1}{8}$ seems something wrong happening @Isham

Comment: they have mulitplied by the factor 2 that have disapeared . in front of the operator do you see it ? @NajmunNahar

Comment: Yes I see but my second term is $-\frac{x}{2i}$ but they manage $\frac{ix}{2}$. Did you notice this$?$ @Isham actually I wrote the line before multiplied by 2.

Comment: yes multiply both numerator and denominator by $i$ that changes the sign of the fraction @NajmunNahar

Comment: Got it @Isham and thanks

Comment: yw @NajmunNahar..thats great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101906/discussion-between-najmunnahar-and-isham).

Comment: you should have a sinus function....that needs a $i$ at the denominator @NajmunNahar. The final result should be real and not complex

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $$\dfrac{1}{1+D} = 1-D+D^2-\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

A way to do basically the same thing with less weird operator manipulation is to think of the procedure as using the integrating factor method on two first order ODEs. If you have say

$$y''+4y=x^2 e^{2ix}$$

then you can write it as

$$(D+2i)(D-2i)y=x^2 e^{2ix}.$$

Then you can let $u=(D-2i)y$ and solve $(D+2i)u=x^2 e^{2ix}$ for $u$ by the integrating factor method. So you have

$$e^{2ix} u = \int x^2 e^{4ix} dx$$

which can be evaluated by integrating by parts. Since you just want a particular solution you can set the constant of integration here equal to zero. You wind up with $u$ being some quadratic polynomial times $e^{2ix}$.

Then with $u$ in hand you just solve

$$(D-2i)y=u$$

and get

$$e^{-2ix}y = \int e^{-2ix} u$$

where now the integral winds up being the integral of just a polynomial, because of the "resonance" in the equation. Setting the constant of integration equal to zero again, you wind up with some cubic polynomial with no constant term times $e^{2ix}$.

That said, if you understand how to do this operator shifting trick that you did to pull the $e^{2ix}$ out (I guess $P(D)^{-1} f = e^{ax} P(D+a)^{-1} e^{-ax} f$?), then you can evaluate $\frac{1}{D+4i} x^2$ by just using the geometric series, expanding in powers of $D$. Thus $\frac{1}{D+4i}=\frac{1}{4i} \frac{1}{1+D/4i}=\frac{1}{4i} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-D/4i)^n$. But now the point is that when you apply this to $x^2$ you get $0$ as soon as $n>2$, so $\frac{1}{D+4i} x^2=\frac{1}{4i} \left ( x^2 - \frac{2x}{4i} + \frac{2}{(4i)^2} \right )$. Then you just apply $D^{-1}$ to that which is just integration.

Comment: @Isham Thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Given differential equation is$$(D^2+4)y=4x^2\cos 2x$$
We have to find the particular integral (P.I.).
\begin{equation}
\text{P.I.}~=4\dfrac{1}{D^2+4}~x^2\cos 2x\\
=\text{R.P. of }~\left(4\dfrac{1}{D^2+4}~x^2~e^{2ix}\right)\\
=4~\cdot~\left[\text{R.P. of }~\left\{e^{2ix}~\dfrac{1}{(D+2i)^2+4}~x^2\right\}\right]\\
=4~\cdot~\left[\text{R.P. of }~\left\{e^{2ix}~\dfrac{1}{D^2+4iD}~x^2\right\}\right]\\
=4~\cdot~\left[\text{R.P. of }~\left\{e^{2ix}~\dfrac{1}{4iD}\left(1+\dfrac{D}{4i}\right)^{-1}~x^2\right\}\right]\\
=4~\cdot~\left[\text{R.P. of }~\left\{e^{2ix}~\dfrac{1}{4iD}\left(1+i\dfrac{D}{4}-\dfrac{D^2}{16}+\cdots\right)~x^2\right\}\right]\\
=4~\cdot~\left[\text{R.P. of }~\left\{e^{2ix}~\dfrac{1}{4iD}\left(x^2+i~\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{1}{8}\right)\right\}\right]\\
=-~\left[\text{R.P. of }~\left\{i~e^{2ix}~\dfrac{1}{D}\left(x^2+i~\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{1}{8}\right)\right\}\right]\\
=-~\left[\text{R.P. of }~\left\{i~e^{2ix}~\left(\dfrac{x^3}{3}+i~\dfrac{x^2}{4}-\dfrac{x}{8}\right)\right\}\right]\\
=-~\left[\text{R.P. of }~\left\{i~\left(\cos 2x+i~\sin 2x\right)~\left(\dfrac{x^3}{3}+i~\dfrac{x^2}{4}-\dfrac{x}{8}\right)\right\}\right]\\
=-~\left[\text{R.P. of }~\left\{\left(i~\cos 2x-~\sin 2x\right)~\left(\dfrac{x^3}{3}+i~\dfrac{x^2}{4}-\dfrac{x}{8}\right)\right\}\right]\\
=-~\left[\text{R.P. of }~\left\{\left(-~\dfrac{x^2}{4}~\cos 2x-\left(\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x}{8}\right)~\sin 2x\right)~+~i~\left(-\dfrac{x^2}{4}\sin 2x+\left(\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x}{8}\right)\cos 2x\right)\right\}\right]\\
=-~\left[-~\dfrac{x^2}{4}~\cos 2x-\left(\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x}{8}\right)~\sin 2x\right]\\
=\dfrac{x^2}{4}~\cos 2x+\left(\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x}{8}\right)~\sin 2x
\end{equation}

Here **R.P.** stands for ***real part***.